# ASP form add email to and also add other fields from form

Tags: html, forms, asp-classic

I have a small issue as I do not know asp. But the pages created for my Uncles website is in asp and the form is as well. I am having trouble getting his form to work and searched through errors and found a pdf from fasthost and I am trying this code but do not understand where I put my email address to send the information to and also how to add other information such as name.

This is the code I am trying:

```
dim oCdoMsg, oCdoConfg, strReferer, strServer, 
strClientIP, strServerIP, blnSpam

 set oCdoMsg = server.createobject("CDO.Message")


strReferer = request.servervariables("HTTP_REFERER") 
strServer = Replace(request.servervariables("SERVER_NAME"), "www.", "") 
strClientIP = request.servervariables("REMOTE_ADDR") 
strServerIP = request.servervariables("LOCAL_ADDR") 
strFrom = "noreply@"  & strServer


intComp = inStr(strReferer, strServer) 
        If intComp > 0 Then 
            blnSpam = False 
        Else 
           ' Spam Attempt Block 
            blnSpam = True 
        End If


oCdoMsg.to = request.form("email") 
oCdoMsg.from = strFrom 
oCdoMsg.Subject = "CDO Test Mail" 
oCdoMsg.Textbody = "This test mail has been sent from 
server " 
oCdoMsg.Textbody = oCdoMsg.Textbody & 
request.servervariables("LOCAL_ADDR") & " via CDO mail 
objects."


strMSSchema = 
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/" 
Set oCdoConfg = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration") 
oCdoConfg.Fields.Item(strMSSchema & "sendusing") = 2 
oCdoConfg.Fields.Item(strMSSchema & "smtpserver") = 
"smtp.fasthosts.co.uk" 
oCdoConfg.Fields.Update 
Set oCdoMsg.Configuration = oCdoConfg


 If NOT blnSpam Then 
oCdoMsg.send 
strResult = "Mail Sent." 
 Else 
 strResult = "Mail Not Sent." 
End If 
response.write strResult 


 set oCdoMsg = nothing 
set oCdoConfg = nothing
```

I would appreciate any help with this, the code that is on the website right now shows a 500 error. Which is why I need to use the code above. I just need help with where to add my domain email and how to bring in other parts of the form such as name into the code above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need enable detailed errors http://goo.gl/Ao3Ss. 
Then you will see what is the error.
And it seems that, you should investigate [VBScript's multiline syntax](http://www.tizag.com/vbscriptTutorial/vbscriptsyntax.php). Because, there are some lines will cause syntax error in your code.
A few examples:

**Wrong:**

```
dim oCdoMsg, oCdoConfg, strReferer, strServer, 
strClientIP, strServerIP, blnSpam

strMSSchema = 
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"

oCdoMsg.Textbody = "This test mail has been sent from 
server "
```

**Correct:**

```
dim oCdoMsg, oCdoConfg, strReferer, strServer, _
strClientIP, strServerIP, blnSpam

strMSSchema = _
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"

oCdoMsg.Textbody = "This test mail has been sent from server "
```

Consider all of these.